# how to call variable result into another select statment in sql stored procedure

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Hi I have one doubt in snowflake
how to use variable result in the next sselect session.

I want stored  one statement result in variable and that variable result need to call another statment  in snowflake server .

```
use schema test.public;
create or replace procedure empresult()
returns table ()
language sql
as
$$
set empresult=(select  deptid from TEST.PUBLIC.DEPT where deptid=10)
declare res resultset(
select * from emp where deptno in ($empresult)
)
begin
return table(res);
end;
$$;
```

above statment getting error.
Syntax error: unexpected 'declare'. (line 4)

please tell me how to write stored procedure query to call the one statment result into another session select statment task.

Comment: Please update your question with the actual error you are getting, but I’m guessing the fact that you’ve spelt “returns” as “retruns” twice may be an issue

Comment: I edited the title because it stated "sql server" though the tag and syntax show that it's for Snowflake.

Comment: Also, where you have “declare reu resultset” do you mean “declare res resultset”?

Comment: getting error: Syntax error: unexpected 'declare'. (line 4)

Answer (score 0):

The sample code is missing colons and the correct syntax for variables.

One possible fix that works:

```sql
create or replace procedure empresult()
returns table ()
language sql
as
$$
declare
 empresult integer; 
begin
 select deptid into :empresult from DEPT where deptid=10;
 let res resultset := (select * from emp where deptno = :empresult);

return table(res);
end;
$$;

call empresult();
```

Staging data:

```sql
create temp table dept as select 10 deptid;
create temp table emp as select 'a' a, 'b' b, 10 deptno;
```